# add " ? " in url via htaccess RewriteRule

Tags: php, .htaccess

i try use RewriteRule in htaccess

i want my url

> site.com/f_search.php?langs=en&langs=en

works like

> site.com/en/new.php?/en/f_search

i used this code in htaccess

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/?/new.php+?+/([^/]*)/?/f_search/?$ f_search.php?langs=$1&langs=$2
```

but its not work with " ? "

if i change new.php+?+  to new.php+@+

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/?/new.php+@+/([^/]*)/?/f_search/?$ f_search.php?langs=$1&langs=$2
```

it works good

> site.com/en/new.php@/en/f_search

any idea to change @ to  ? in my url ???

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The question mark and what follows is *not* part of the subject the pattern of a RewriteRule is matched against. That is clearly documented. Instead you need to use a `RewriteCond` to access the content of the query string.

I assume this is roughly what you are looking for, though you might have to tweak it to match your actual situation:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^/([a-z]+)/f_search$
RewriteRule ^/?(?:([a-z]+)/)?new\.php$ /f_search.php?langs=$1&langs=%1
```

From your question it is unclear where the two values for the argument "langs" in the rewrite target should get taken. So you may have to adjust that to your needs in the rule.

Also it is puzzling that you are trying to set that argument "langs" *twice* ... That makes little sense, the second attempt will simply overwrite the value of the first attempt when those values are handed over to your php based logic.

The documentation of the rewriting module for the apache http server offer a lot of precise help and good examples: https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html

Comment: hello arkascha 

thanks for trying help me 

it was mistake when i used lang twice its langs and langs2

but your code not working with me i dont know what is wrong

my code is working 

i just want just change  @ to ? only to be like that

[link](> site.com/en/new.php@/en/f_search)

to

[link](> site.com/en/new.php?/en/f_search)

can u help me

Comment: The code in the answer works as far as I understood your question: https://htaccess.madewithlove.com?share=68636d5d-7e79-4f19-8475-420885450968 You certainly have to adapt it to your needs, I already mentioned that in the answer. If you fail to get it to work then "not working" does not help. You will need to be specific: what does that actually mean? What happens if you request `https://example.com/en/new.php?/en/f_search`? What result to you get, what does your browsers console say, what does your http server's error log say?

Comment: i would like to thank you

you alright it was my mistake i used your code dirct with out any change 

i understanded your comment good then i edit it 

and its work good

Answer (score 0):

the final code

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^/?([a-z]+)/new.php$ f_search.php?langs=$1 [L,NC]
```